# Convert submit button to ActionLink

Tags: asp.net-mvc, button, actionlink

Is there a way to convert the submit button with an `ActionLink`?

I got this `ActionLink` which redirects the user to the index page:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Cancel", "Index", null, new { @class = "k-button" })
```

And a save button which submits to save whatever is created or altered:

```
<input type="submit" value="Save" />
```

It would be nice to have the submit button the same code as the `ActionLink`.

Comment: I understand you want an ActionLink, but, why don't you change your code to an `ActionLink`? Or you need something more specific?

Comment: Why would you want this? The only way to submit a form via a link (`<a>`) is with JavaScript, and that's never pretty.

Comment: @FelipeOriani, well that was basically my question, how would i use an ActionLink instead of the <input> tag. I have the ActionLink styled as a button.

Comment: @RudiVisser, it would make the code more prettier and more readable.

Comment: `@Html.ActionLink("Cancel", "Index", null, new { @class = "k-button", onclick = "document.forms[0].submit(); return false;" })` - I don't think that's prettier ;)

Comment: You want something like this: `@Html.Button("type")` or `@Html.Submit()`, right? If yes you could write your own helpers.

Comment: @AliRızaAdıyahşi, yea thats what i want. How do you create something like that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use an `<a>` tag directly, try something like this:

```
<a onclick="$('#YourForm').submit();" class="k-button">Save</a>
```

And in your Action Post of your form:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Post(..)
{
   /// process something...
   return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

### HTML Helper

As in the comments, you could create your own html helper, try this:

```
using System;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace MvcApplication.Helpers
{
     public static class HtmlExtensions
     {
          public static string SubmitLink(this HtmlHelper helper, string text, string formId)
          {
               return string.Format("<a class='k-button' onclick='$(\"#{1}\").submit();'>{1}</a>", text, formdId);
          }
     }
}
```

And use it:

```
@Html.SubmitLink("Save", "formId")
```

Comment: hi, your code contains some errors. This method is not returning anything, i've added a 'return' keyword. But it also just prints out what's inside it, instead of making it act like a button. Also, don't you need some 'tag builder' for this?

Comment: Yes, you`re right, I`ve correct my code :), but it is just some help, you could take the sugestions to get the final solution :)