# Asp.net MVC action link to post with routed parameters

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Hi I have the following data table in which u can click move button , the issue is that it always use get link instead of post how to apply post with parameters

```
<div class="box-body">
                    @using (@Html.BeginForm("QueueDetails", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
                    {
                        <table id="example1">

                            <tbody>
                                @foreach (var errorMesseage in Model.ErrorMesseages)
                                {

                                <tr>

                                    <td>@errorMesseage</td>

                                    <td>
                                        @Html.ActionLink(
                                             "Move",
                                             "QueueDetails",
                                             new { errorMesseage = @errorMesseage, model = Model },
                                             new { @class = "saveButton", onclick = "return false;" })

                                    </td>


                                </tr>
                                }

                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    }                    

                </div>
```

$(document).ready(function () {
    createChart();

```
$('.saveButton').click(function () {

    if(confirm('Are you sure you wish to Move this messeage back?'))
    {
        $(this).closest('form')[0].submit();
    }
});
```

});

it always redirect to the get with url like `Home/QueueDetails?errorMesseage=Error%20messeage%201&model=xxxx`

Comment: You can use "@Ajax.ActionLink" with new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "POST" } instead of "@Html.ActionLink".  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.ajax.ajaxextensions.actionlink.aspx

Comment: How does your `Move` method looks like ?

Comment: Have a look this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14707417/3814721)